# Calling JQuery Button Clicks/Form Submit in Firebase Functions and Hosting

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, firebase

I am trying to make a website using Firebase Functions and Hosting Feature. Everything works perfectly but for some reason when the user tries to fill the form, the website reloads. I am trying to place an onClick Listener on the button in the form or attach the onSubmit to the form. But nothing gets called. I don't know what I am doing wrong. Any help will be appreciated.

```
<form id="join-us-form" class="container" onsubmit="joinUsButtonCalled()">
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <label for="joinUsFullName" class="sr-only">Full Name</label>
                                <div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0" style="border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 5px">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: transparent">
                                        <i class="fal fa-user" style="color: white;"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinUsFullName" placeholder="Your Name"
                                           required style="background: transparent; color: white">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Please provide us with your name.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <label for="joinUsEmailAddress" class="sr-only">Email Address</label>
                                <div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0" style="border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 5px">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: transparent">
                                        <i class="fal fa-envelope" style="color: white;"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="joinUsEmailAddress"
                                           placeholder="Email Address"
                                           required style="background: transparent; color: white">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Please provide a valid email.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-row">
                            <div class="form-group col-sm-12">
                                <label for="joinUsWorkAs" class="sr-only">Work as..</label>
                                <div class="input-group mb-2 mb-sm-0" style="border: 1px solid white; border-radius: 5px">
                                    <div class="input-group-addon" style="background-color: transparent">
                                        <i class="fal fa-tasks" style="color: white;"></i>
                                    </div>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="joinUsWorkAs"
                                           placeholder="e.g: Designer, App Developer ..."
                                           required style="background: transparent; color: white">
                                    <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                        Please provide a valid work as.
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <button id="joinUsButton" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded" type="submit" onClick="joinUsButtonCalled()">Get in Touch</button>
                    </form>



<script>
    function joinUsButtonCalled(event){
        $('#join-us-form').preventDefault();
        console.log('I am being called here in Join Us ()');
        event.preventDefault();
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using JQUERY I would try something like this:

```
$('#join-us-form').submit(function(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault(); //to stop the form from submitting
    //do your validation stuff
    this.submit(); // If all the validations succeeded
});

$('#joinUsButton').on('click', function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault(); //to stop the form from submitting
     //do your validation stuff
     $('#join-us-form').submit();// If all the validations succeeded
});
```

The problem with your script was that "event" was actually "undefined" cause "`onSubmit`" doesn't pass any argument to the function "`joinUsButtonCalled`".

Same for "`$('#join-us-form').preventDefault();`" cause `preventDefault()` is not a method of a generic JQUERY object, it belong to the EventObject, like the ones fired by a user click.
I guess your console was full of "undefined" error.
Finally you can get rid of the "onSumbit" and "onClick" attribute:

```
<form id="join-us-form" class="container">
...
    <button id="joinUsButton" class="btn btn-warning btn-rounded" type="submit">Get in Touch</button>
</form>
```